# Email with commas in TextArea Validation (MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, email, textarea

I have a textarea where user can put emails with comma as a separator. Is there any way to walidate this so I can return error message in case he puts email in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would use a regex to extract all valid emails and ignore everything else. If there are no valid emails, then present a message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom validator for your case. That way, you can parse the list by comma and check each one individually (do a search for custom validator in mvc 3 and you should find plenty of examples)

Comment: ... but for the love of `$dmr` make sure your "validator" doesn't prohibit legal addresses such as `*@example.nu` or `me+stackoverflow=com@example.net` or `example@temporary.domain.in.case.youre.a.spammer.example.org`